# Two threads referring one variable

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I am running the below class .

```
public class RunThreads implements Runnable {
    static int  i;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunThreads job = new RunThreads();
        Thread alpha = new Thread(job);
        Thread beta = new Thread(job);
        alpha.setName("Alpha");
        beta.setName("beta");
        alpha.start();
        beta.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        for(;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
        }
    }
}
```

And my output is :

```
beta0
beta1
Alpha0
beta2
beta4
beta5
beta6
Alpha3
Alpha8
beta7
Alpha9
```

I understand I will get different outputs every time I execute it. My question is, why does the output have the value of `i` as `0` twice, for both the `alpha` and `beta` threads i.e. `Alpha0` and `beta0`.

The value of `i` has been incremented to `1` by the `beta` thread. So, how does the `alpha` thread print out `Alpha0`

I maybe missing something very obvious here. Thanks !

Comment: Your threads are racing. They're both trying to read and update the same variable, and there's no guarantee what order the operations will happen in. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example

Comment: @khelwood: Whoops, missed that :)

Comment: @JonSkeet , the `i` variable is static , so the threads share the variable here, right ?

Comment: The answer is: use AtomicInteger, if you want to do this :)

Comment: Yup, I'd missed that - didn't read the question thoroughly enough. Apologies.

Comment: @JonSkeet using an AtomicInteger wouldn't help if the OP first gets and print the value, then increment its value. The structure of the loop needs to change, too.

Comment: @khelwood I understand both the threads are reading from the same variable, but when the `beta` thread increments `i` to `1`, how does the `alpha` thread printout `Alpha0` ?

Comment: @tarunkt `i++` is "get the current value of i; add 1 to that value; store that value". If another thread jumps in and alters `i` part way through that, you won't get the result you expect.

Comment: The variable is not volatile, so each thread might still see old, obsolete values of `i`. You really need to read about concurrency, because those kinds of things happen all the times if you're not fully aware of the limitations of the memory model.

Comment: The document you should read (or google around for summaries) is  JSR  133, The Java Memory Model.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, absolutely - didn't want to get into that in a comment, but it's in my answer :)

Comment: @khelwood , if `beta1` was printed , it means the value of `i` has been incremented to `1`, so when the print statement in `alpha` executes and tries to get the value of `i` , how can it get `0` for it to print `Alpha0` ?

Comment: @tarunkt: 1. thread B reads i (0); 2. thread B concatenates i with the thread name; 3. thread A reads i (0), prints it and increments it, twice. 4. thread B prints its concatenated string, containing the value 0.

Answer (score 3):

Things are scary when you access shared data with no synchronization etc:

- There's no guarantee that the Alpha thread reading `i` will see the "latest" update from the `beta` thread or vice versa
- It's possible for both threads to start `i++` at roughly the same time... and as `i++` is basically:

  ```
  int tmp = i;
  tmp++;
  i = tmp;
  ```

  you can easily "lose" increments

If you want to make this thread-safe, you should use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class RunThreads implements Runnable {
    static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RunThreads job = new RunThreads();
        Thread alpha = new Thread(job);
        Thread beta = new Thread(job);
        alpha.setName("Alpha");
        beta.setName("beta");
        alpha.start();
        beta.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        int local;
        while ((local = counter.getAndIncrement()) < 10) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + local);
        }
    }
}
```

Your output may still appear to be in the wrong *order* (because the alpha thread may "start" writing "Alpha0" while the beta thread "starts" writing "beta1" but the beta thread gets the lock on console output first), but you'll only see each count once. Note that you have to use the result of `getAndIncrement()` for both the checking and the printing - if you called `counter.get()` in the body of the loop, you could still see duplicates due to the interleaving of operations.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer here would be that whether or not the variable is volatile or atomic or whatever, both your threads start out when the variable value is 0, and only change it *after* the print.

This means that both threads can reach the "print" line before either of them reached the `i++`.

Which means that both are very likely to print 0, unless one of them is delayed long enough for the other one to update the variable (at which point the question of memory model and data visibility arise).

Comment: if `beta1` was printed , it means the value of `i` has been incremented to `1`, so when the print statement in `alpha` executes and tries to get the value of `i` , how can it get `0` for it to print `Alpha0` ?

Comment: Well, @tarunkt, that's where the "memory model" issue comes. The fact that you change an un-synchronized variable in one thread does not imply that the other thread sees the new value. It sees its own cached value.

Answer (score 0):

"While" thread A is doing its update, thread B is reading that value.

Like in:

```
A: prints i (current value 0)
B: prints i (current value 0)
A: stores 1 to i
```

You can't assume that those **two** actions:

```
for(;i<10;i++){ // increasing the loop counter
```

and

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + i);
```

printing the loop counter happen in "one shot". To the contrary.

Both threads execute the corresponding instructions in parallel; and there are **absolutely** no guarantees on the outcome of that.

Comment: Correct, that was misleading; removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

Threads might run on separate cores in multicore architecture and each core has it's own registry set or local cache, as long as you don't invalidate a cache the running core might not reach to a RAM memory to get up-to-date value and will use the cached one. To make it work as you expected it the variable would have to be marked as volatile, which would invalidate a cache on each write to this memory location and fetch the value directly from RAM.

Update:
As was pointed in comments - volatile is not enough to keep the value up to date, there is a read and write operation on i++. To make it work AtomicInteger would be enough, or slightly more expensive locking around i++.

Comment: Using a volatile variable would only solve a small portion of this. It doesn't help the fact that increments are non-atomic, nor that the increment is separate from the fetch.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, you would still get race condition on who writes first. You would get values from a range from 10-20 depending if the threads squeeze between read of i operation and performing write to memory after ++ operation.